# Mostrar contenido de variable en Spinner (Android Studio)

Tags: variables, android-spinner

gracias a todos por su tiempo.

tengo una consulta, es posible introducir el valor de una variable en un Spinner.
por ejemplo:

```
int f1 = 1;
```

y que ese "1", pueda ser mostrado al desplegar el Spinner.
Si es posible, agradezco puedan mostrarme como.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Saludos Carlos, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo que veas el tour https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y del mismo modo obtengas tu primera medalla, revisa también cómo realizar preguntas en el siguiente enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask finalmente me gustaría compartir contigo un buen curso introductorio de Android: https://www.edx.org/course/android-introduccion-a-la-programacion

Comment: **Es posible.** Agrega el código que estas realizando, revisa [ask]. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio,saludos!